# export object schema(objects, fields, datatypes ) from sandbox to excel?

Tags: object

Is it possible to export object schema(objects, fields, datatypes ) from sandbox to excel?

I tried following tools no use-Cloud Converter, EasyDescribe and Object Snapshot.

Please let me know, Greatly Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try **Salesforce Schema Lister** from https://schemalister.herokuapp.com.  It doesn't contain an Export functionality but you can easily copy the list view results into Excel.